# What permissions do I need to get the request digest of a SharePoint site using SharePoint's REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

What permissions do I need to get the request digest of a SharePoint site using SharePoint's REST API?

If I have view only access to the site but I have contribute access to a list on the site can I still get the request digest?

Comment: Have you tried a Post call?

Comment: yes, I have tried a Post call.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The response is redirected to the login page (with an ok status) so there is no actual error message. I'm assuming it's an authorization error since I'm redirected to the login page.

Comment: See if this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408413/http-post-how-to-send-authorization-header/39411480

Comment: I'm making the request directly from c# code, I don't think this is the issue. Thanks though, that actually helped me with something unrelated.

Comment: You can try passing authorization token.

Comment: I am, actually it's pretty much exactly like the authorization header in the link you sent me.